# Ubuntu 20 hangs after wifi toggle

Tags: wireless, network-manager, 20.04

I am running ubuntu 20.04 on dell xps 13. My wifi stops working every once in a while (while still showing connected. This used to happen before upgrading to the latest version as well, but switching it off and on fixed the issue). Now after upgrading to 20.04, whenever this happens and I turn the wifi off, weird things start to happen. The wifi functionality stops working completely. I am unable to turn it off or on. Some apps get hanged permanently. For example, typing `sudo` in a terminal doesn't output anything and just hangs. The only solution is rebooting. Does anyone know how to fix this?